# Filtering Arrays with Multiple Values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm filtering some arrays of objects by keyword using the JavaScript Array Filter. Initial, I had an array of objects:

```
  let works = [
    { title: ' work 1', medium: 'tax1' },
    { title: ' work 2', medium: 'tax2' },
    { title: ' work 3', medium: 'tax3' },
    { title: ' work 4', medium: 'tax2' },
    { title: ' work 5', medium: 'tax1' }
  ]
```

And could filter the array by the 'medium' in this manner:

```
    mediumFilter(taxonomy) {
        return works.filter(item => {
            return (
              item.medium.indexOf(taxonomy) > -1
            );
        });
    },
```

When I pass the *taxonomy* variable to the *mediumFilter()*, in this case 'tax1' or so -- I get an array that includes the items containing that specific medium.

This was initial -- now that my project is getting more complex, I find myself struggling. My new array includes a nested array, which are the values to match in the filtering.

```
  let works = [
    { title: ' work 1', medium: [ 'tax1', 'tax3' ] },
    { title: ' work 2', medium: [ 'tax1' ] },
    { title: ' work 3', medium: [ 'tax3' ] },
    { title: ' work 4', medium: [ 'tax2', 'tax1' ] },
    { title: ' work 5', medium: [ 'tax1' ] }
  ]
```

Notice how the medium is an array holding multiple strings.

I'm looking for some assistance on how to approach this. I need my function to return items that match the variable im passing. As some works could have multiple mediums, I need to be able to filter by multiple values. If the array of mediums has multiple values, only one needs to match.

Thanks!

*btw im using vue which is not relevant to the question but syntax of my examples might not be exact.*

Comment: what should be the result for this `mediumFilter(['tax3','tax2'])` ?

Comment: Hi -- User can only filter by one category at this stage, so the variable to pass into the function will always be a single string! Still this is very important to consider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and check the string.

```js
let works = [{ title: 'work 1', medium: ['tax1', 'tax3'] }, { title: 'work 2', medium: ['tax1'] }, { title: 'work 3', medium: ['tax3'] }, { title: 'work 4', medium: ['tax2', 'tax1'] }, { title: 'work 5', medium: ['tax1'] }],
   mediumFilter = taxonomy => works.filter(item => item.medium.includes(taxonomy));

console.log(mediumFilter('tax3'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :~)!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right then this should work:

```
function mediumFilter(taxonomy) {
    return works.filter(x => x.medium.indexOf(taxonomy) > -1 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually this was my initial approach -- it works if the Array _works_ property _medium_ is a single string. Since my _medium_ now is an array, some nested logic is needed to check multiple matches

Answer (score 0):

```
mediumFilter(taxonomy) {
    return works.forEach(item => {
        for(let i = 0; i < item.medium.length; i++){
            if(item.medium[i].indexOf(taxonomy) > -1){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
},
```

I believe this is what you had in mind. If taxonomy is an array (and always will be, no doing `mediumFilter('tax1')` and `mediumFilter(['tax1','tax2'])` then you can do this as well:

```
mediumFilter(taxonomy) {
    return works.forEach(item => {
        for(let i = 0; i < item.medium.length; i++){
            for(elem of taxonomy){
                if(item.medium[i].indexOf(elem) > -1){
                     return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
},
```

Comment: Thank you! This approach helps me understand the logic needed to achieve what I want! In my case I was expecting it to return a new array -- instead of a boolean. I updated my question!

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the function to accept arrays in both the object and the search query

```js
function mediumFilter(taxonomy) {
    taxonomy = Array.isArray(taxonomy) ? taxonomy : [taxonomy];
    return works.filter(item => {
        let medium = Array.isArray(item.medium) ? item.medium : [item.medium];
        return taxonomy.some(med => medium.includes(med));
    });
}

let works = [
  {title: ' work 1', medium: ['tax1', 'tax2']}, 
  {title: ' work 2', medium: 'tax2'}, 
  {title: ' work 3', medium: 'tax3'}, 
  {title: ' work 4', medium: 'tax4'}, 
  {title: ' work 5', medium: 'tax5'}
];

function log(x) {console.log( x.map( y => y.title) )}

log( mediumFilter('tax1') );           // 1
log( mediumFilter(['tax1', 'tax2']) ); // 1, 2
log( mediumFilter('tax2') );           // 1, 2
log( mediumFilter(['tax4']) );         // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let works = [
  { title: ' work 1', medium: [ 'tax1', 'tax3' ] },
  { title: ' work 2', medium: [ 'tax1' ] },
  { title: ' work 3', medium: [ 'tax3' ] },
  { title: ' work 4', medium: [ 'tax2', 'tax1' ] },
  { title: ' work 5', medium: [ 'tax1' ] }
]

  function mediumFilter(taxonomy) {
      return works.filter(item => {
          return item.medium.filter(subitem => {
              return (
                  subitem.indexOf(taxonomy) > -1
              );
          });
      });
  }

  console.log(mediumFilter('tax1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid nested loops. I would change the data structure, to accommodate a more efficient search.`{tax1:['work 1','work 2'], tax2:[],}`